# How to parallelize multidimensional for-loops in with calculation done in outer loops in OpenCL?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I am trying to parallelize a code that looks like this using OpenCL run on a GPU:

```cpp
int pos = 0;
for (int x=0 ; x<x_len ; x++){
    //do some expensive calculation like
    int value = pow(24, x);
    for (int y=0 ; y<y_len ; y++){
        for (int z=0 ; z<z_len ; z++){
            //do some expensive calculation that depends on value
            //but is very unlikely to have a positive result needed
            //to save in global memmoy - something like
            if ((value * y * z) % 456 = 0){ 
                // save position that had positive result
                output[pos] = x*y_len*z_len+y*z_len + z; 
                pos++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(`y_len` and `z_len` are small enough so that a (1,`y_len`,`z_len`) lokal workgroup is possible, just in case that is important)

My current solution has 2 kernels, one calculating the outer calculation and saving the result to global memory and the second using that calculated  data and calculate the inner calculation (using `atomic_add` for pos). That works fine but my actual code needs more data to be saved than just one integer (it is actually 2 integer and 2 longs) per x iteration, so that global memory is used up quite fast. That means that I need to split the kernel calls and iterate over the calls in the host code a lot of times.
So my question is, if there a better ways to parallelize that code?

Comment: If you are at limits of video-ram, maybe it is at the limit of gpu too? How many bytes does this use per split-kernel and in total?

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik what exactly do you mean by the limit of the gpu? In my calculation is basicly infinitly expandable in the x direction, the only problem being the video-ram restriction if I have to use 2 kernels as the final result is only small (list of the successfull calculations). Per instance 2 Integer and 2 Longs (total of 24 bytes) need to be stored, restricting x_len to about 35000000 (that is actually small considering that the final result probably only consists of about 1 to 2 data)